# execute ajax when a page load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to execute ajax when  a page load but it does not work!.
I want to run the code only when the second page loads.
This jquery code:

```
$("#mydiv").on('load', this, function(){        
         alert('loaded');

    return false;           

});
```

html code: 
the second page has got a div:

```
 <div id"mydiv"></div>
```

Please help me to fix this issue so I can process the ajax request.
Thank you.

Comment: *"it does work"*. So what ?

Comment: So I can process the ajax request.

Comment: Does the `alert('loaded')` ever happen?  Also, here's some docs on [the `.on` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [the `load` event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: the alert does not run which means the code is not working.

Comment: what about you update your question with the right words then?

Answer (score 1):

why dont you execute ajax on document ready ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){        

    alert('loaded');
});
```

Comment: Because I want to run the code only when the second page loads.

Comment: how you execute ajax to load second page? cant you assign handler to ajax request as `success handler` to execute after success ajax ?